# how to retrieve data from firebase to flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-dependencies

I want to get data from firebase to my flutter app. I created a collection at firebase but don't know how to use it on flutter. Already I've done the setup process between flutter and firebase and also added necessary dependencies. but now I need help to get data from firebase. collection name '0xethocity' ;

[image: Here is The Image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation, try to implement it by yourself. Let us know if you get stuck.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios